# Excel dll addin does not load

Tags: excel, dll, add-in

I will try to make an Excel dll add-in. But I have started with the example called 'generic' in the SDK (http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=23242), compiled it and tried to load it in Excel. But nothing happens. If I start Excel with VS2010 debugger it doesn't even shows that Excel loads the dll. None of the  addin functionality is available, and if I set breakpoints in the dll and then start Excel as debug target, no breakpoint is ever hit. Actually, they remain with the "empty-circle", meaning that to the knowledge of the debugger the dll has not been loaded.

I have carefully checked the security settings, and there is nothing that could inhibit the addin functionality there.

Any ideas?

I'm working with Excel 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely sounds like security settings to me. Maybe you should see if http://xll.codeplex.com works for you.

Comment: Thanks. I already tried that. It doesn't. Could you give a check list of security settings to change?

Comment: It works with Excel 2003 and the plugin you suggested. So it is probably security in Excel 2010. Accepting your answer.